# How to manipulate data by row in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I'm getting a bit confused. I've got data like this in a data frame

```
    index  times
1       1  56.60
2       1 150.75
3       1 204.41
4       2  44.71
5       2  98.03
6       2 112.20
```

and I know that the times indexed 1 are biased, whereas the times indexed otherwise are not. I need to create a copy of that data frame removing the bias from the samples indexed 1. I've been trying several combinations of apply, by, and the likes. The closest I got was with

```
by(lct, lct$index, function(x) { if(x$index == 1) x$times = x$times-50 else x$times = x$times } )
```

which returned an object of class `by`, which is unusable for me. I need to write the data back to a csv file in the same format (index, times) of the original file. Ideas?

Comment: So you need to subtract 50 to each `times` if `index` is 1?

Comment: Precisely like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
df$times[df$index ==1] <- df$times[df$times == 1] - 50
```

The trick here is to take the subset of `df$times` that fits your filter, and realize that R can also assign to a subset.

Alternatively, you can use `ifelse`:

```
df$times = ifelse(df$index == 1, df$times - 50, df$times)
```

and use it in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(index = sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE), 
                value = runif(100)) %>% arrange(index)
df %>% mutate(value = ifelse(index == 1, value - 50, value))
#  index     value
#1     1 -49.95827
#2     1 -49.98104
#3     1 -49.44015
#4     1 -49.37316
#5     1 -49.76286
#6     1 -49.22133
#etc
```

Comment: Seems to work fine. You may need `df$times[df$index == 1] <- df$times[df$times == 1] - 50` otherwise R throws a warning on the length of the replacement. I'll wait for more solutions before accepting :)

Comment: I also added a solution using `ifelse`, I think that is more readable.

Comment: I agree, I was hoping for something like that.

Answer (score 0):

How about,

```
index <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
times <- c(56.60, 150.75, 204.41, 44.71, 98.03, 112.20)
df <- data.frame(index, times)
df$times <- ifelse(df$index == 1, df$times - 50, df$times)


> df
#index  times
#1     1   6.60
#2     1 100.75
#3     1 154.41
#4     2  44.71
#5     2  98.03
#6     2 112.20
```

Comment: Directly write `df <- data.frame(index, times)`. And `df$times <- with(df, ifelse(index == 1, times -50, times))`.

Comment: How would `with` help me in this?

Comment: It avoids all these `$`.

Comment: I @pascal means that the code is more easy to read, and contains less superfluous code. I like using dplyr even more in getting clean code, see the example in my question.